# Accessibility of Google presentations on html page with ChromeVox

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, presentation

I'm trying to make accessible to screen readers the google presentations, I have created a page where you can view the presentation via embed, I tried to read the texts and images with ChromeVox, there are alternative texts but it seems that you can not read the contents but the slide titles only.

How can I fix it and make content accessible even to those who can not see?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a plain text transcript / alternative. Also note that the typical screen reader user is not using ChromeVox but it using NVDA, JAWS, VoiceOver, etc. Test in those.

[Google's own documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1634140) targets how an editor creates a presentation, not how a user can consume one. [Same with its tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWZVQ-vldEk).